# why can't I access full html of this page using urllib, beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

I'm new in web scraping and for learning purpose I want to find all href link in https://retty.me/ website.
But I found that my code only find one link in that website. But I viwed page source it has many link which didn't print. I also print full page where only one link contains.
what did I do wrong?

please correct me.

here is my python code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
data=[]
html = urlopen('https://retty.me')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
print(soup)
for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^https://")}):
    data.append(link.attrs['href'])



file=open('scraped_data.txt','w')
for item in data:
    file.write("%s\n"%item)
file.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enter the message shown in the html you get into google translate it says "We apologize for your trouble".
They don't want people scraping their site so they filter requests based on the user agent. You just need to add a user agent to the request header that looks like a browser.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

data=[]

url = 'https://retty.me'
req = Request(
    url, 
    data=None, 
    headers={
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
    }
)
html = urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
print(soup)
for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^https://")}):
    data.append(link.attrs['href'])

for item in data:
    print(item)
```

In fact, this particular site only requires the presence of the user agent header and will accept any user agent even an empty string. The requests library as mentioned by Rishav provides a user agent by default, that's why it works without adding a custom header there.

Comment: I have one more question. Is that User-Agent parameter fixed? I've almost same parameters everywhere. Thank you.

Comment: You can use anything for user agent. Usually the app making the request will put something to identify itself like 'Mozilla...' or 'Chrome...' or 'python-requests...'. Web sites may filter requests based on the user agent field though so for scraping it's best to make it look like the scraper is a web browser. You can view the user agent used by chrome in the network tab for example.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why the website returns different HTML when used with urllib, but you can use the excellent `requests` library which is much easier to use than `urllib` anyway.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests

data = []
html = requests.get('https://retty.me').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^https://")}):
    data.append(link.attrs['href'])
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the official documentation for requests [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) and for Beautiful Soup [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# your Response object called response
response = requests.get('https://retty.me')

# your html as string
html = response.text

#verify that you get the correct html code
print(html)

#make the html, a soup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# initialization of your list
data = []

# append to your list all the URLs found within a page’s <a> tags
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    data.append(link.get('href'))

#print your list items
print(data)
```